# Find elliptic function $f$ satisfying the condition

Tags: complex-analysis

Find an elliptic function $f$ with period lattice $\Omega=\mathbb{Z}\omega_1+\mathbb{Z}\omega_2$ such that $\deg(f)=2$ and $f$ has $2$ poles of order $1$, then express $f$ in term of the Weierstrass $\wp$-function.

Comment: Er...just like that? This is advanced stuff: I bet you've tried something that you can show us: where are you stuck?